# php sessions and different page views

Tags: php, session, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to solve a php exercise and I got no clue how to display different parts of the website. I know you can include other pages(.php) with using *switch*.

Basically, if you visit site first time, you will see message: *Children are bored, take them to park(link)* , after pressing the link you will get into park view and it's message is displayed with ball picture and three child's picture. If you click on ball, one child's(chosen randomly) will get a 1 catch and you will be taken back into home/default view. Catches will be saved in session, so if you go back into park, you will see who caught the ball and you can repeat the process. Can you give me some tips how to do it? Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

    <style>
    #children {
        float:left;
        margin: 0px 100px;
    }
    #ball {
        margin:100px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Use this to make different page views -->

    <!-- home -->
    <p>Children are bored, take them to <a href="?mode=park">park</a></p>

<!-- park -->
<p>For children to be more fun, throw them a ball, you can also go <a href="?mode=home">back home</a></p>
<div id="children">
    <!-- Repeat this part to make 3 children -->
    <div>
        <img src="child.png" alt="child" width="100"/><br/>
        here child's name -  here amount of balls child has caught.
    </div>
    <!-- end -->
</div>
<div id="ball">
    <a href="?mode=throw">    <!--after throwing,  add 1 catch to random child and return home page-->
        <img src="ball.png" width="100" alt="ball" />
    </a>
    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would say use a cookie instead of a session

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['counter']++;

if($_SESSION['counter'] > 0 && $_SESSION['counter'] < 5) {
    // Blah
}else if($_SESSION['counter'] > 5 && $_SESSION['counter'] < 10) {
    // Blah
}
```

Start the session -> Increase session variable by one(for page view) -> depending on value of the variable it does different things

EDIT:

```
if($_SESSION['mode'] == "park") {
    echo "<park image>";
}else if($_SESSION['mode'] == "city") {
    echo "<city image>";
}else {
    echo "<default image>";
}
```

Change these two concepts to fit what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I understand how sessions work, but my main problem is I don't know how to display parts of the website aka if SESSION mode?=park then show only the park paragraphs with children pictures and a ball and hide everything else.

Comment: Its the same concept as the code above. Ill add that for you.

Comment: you don't have to use echo statements (especially if you have multiple lines of html) you could just do something like <?php if(x=y){?><a image><?php else{ ?><b image><?php } ?>

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_GET['child'] == null){
// set a counter for each child for one time only.
$_SESSION['counter'] = array(1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0); 
}

if($_GET['child'] != null){
  $childIndex = $_GET['child'];
  $_SESSION['counter'][$childIndex]++;
}

$_prob = rand(1, 3);    // set probability for choosing the child image every time the page is loading. 


?>

// in the ball tag you can insert the increment within that using javascript . something like: 

<div id="ball">
    <a href="?mode=throw">    
    <!--after throwing,  add 1 catch to random child and return home page-->
        <img src="ball.png" width="100" alt="ball" onclick="increment(<?php echo $_prob; ?>);"/>
    </a>
 </div>
<script>
  function increment(prob){
     window.location="yourlink?child="+prob;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: As I understand that this part is for throwing the ball and then saving the catch. My main problem atm is though, that I don't know how to include/show  _Children are bored, take them to park(link)_ first time you are at site and nothing else. Then after you click link(mode changes in address bar), it takes you to park page where are pictures.

Comment: You need to explain what change you have made ......

Comment: the great thing about the javascript code: window.location="yourlink?child="+prob; that you can send any variable to any page. and from there you can handle it by using php and work with it as a GET variable. using the php keyword : $_GET['the variable name']; from here you can set it as a variable, session, index, or anything you need.

Comment: But I only have one page. Basically I have to hide some parts website body depending on what mode I am on.